# Exception for image size

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I set exception for image size? for instance, I am trying to select a file (image) through openfiledialogue but I want to throw an exception if the image size is less than 250x150 (assume).

```
public void select_image_button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button b in game_panel1.Controls)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png";
        // openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\DELL_PC";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string a = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Image ToBeCropped = Image.FromFile(a, true);
            ReturnCroppedList(ToBeCropped, 320, 320);
            pictureBox1.Image = ToBeCropped;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            AddImagesToButtons(images);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy. After you load the image, check the size of the image. If the size is less than whatever, throw an exception. Where are you having trouble? Can you show us the code you have?

Comment: i guess in the else statement i've to use TRY CATCH FINALLY ..?

Comment: [Exception Handling Fundamentals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w8f0bss(v=vs.110).aspx). [C# - Exception Handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm).

Comment: @AmberYaseen Please describe again, in different words, what your goal is. Be detailed. Do you want to CAUSE an exception, or PREVENT an exception?

Comment: You really shouldn't throw an exception for this. Exceptions are for unanticipated situations. Receiving an image that is too big should be anticipated and handled as part of normal program flow.

Comment: ...and remove the `foreach` as well. You are neither using the loop variable, nor are you really looping, since you break in any case.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i want to create an exception ( user defined exception ) for checking the image size , if too small then it should display a popup or whatever. its for a puzzle slider game . Moreover, i used break keyword because after i clicked a button to open file and select desired file, it would open the file once and again would open the dialoguebox, so to avoid that i used break and after that it worked fine

Comment: @AmberYaseen I think "exception" is the wrong word. You just want to pop up a message to the user without crashing the program? Never mind about `break`, I was mistaken.

Comment: foreach is used because im accessing another class button @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: This is clearly a misuse of exceptions. Don't do it, even if the (terrible) overhead is meaningless for user triggered action. It is bad style not something you should get used to!

Comment: @AmberYaseen what you are looking for is to validate the image size , please look at my answer and let me know if it meets what you need and mark it as an answered question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class used for when the program receive errors that occur during application execution in other words it's  for when the programme receive an unusual behavior  , for exemple something that will make the programme 'crash' or stop working

Exeptions and validations are 2 different but similar concept

What you are looking for is a **validation mechanism** and there are many way to do so :

One of the thing you can do is force the image to the desired size this will avoid undesired image size :

```
  foreach (Button b in game_panel1.Controls)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png";
            // openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\DELL_PC";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                string a = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                Image ToBeCropped = Image.FromFile(a, true);
                ReturnCroppedList(ToBeCropped, 320, 320);
                pictureBox1.Image = ToBeCropped;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
               pictureBox1.Size = new Size(210, 110);///--add here your desired size
                AddImagesToButtons(images);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But if you insist on displaying an error you can use a message box instead ,make a loop and when the desired size is met exit the loop , otherwise display a message Box to the user:

```
foreach (Button b in game_panel1.Controls)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png";
    // openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\DELL_PC";

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        bool correctSize=false;
        var imageH=null;
        var imageW=null
                while(!correctSize) //make a loop so only desired size will be taken 
                {
                    string a = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    Image ToBeCropped = Image.FromFile(a, true);

                    *ReturnCroppedList(ToBeCropped, 320, 320);
                    pictureBox1.Image = ToBeCropped;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    if(PictureBox1.Image.Size.Width==yourWidth && PictureBox1.Image.Size.height==yourHeight) //Validate size 
                    { correctSize =true; 
                      AddImagesToButtons(images);
                    break;
                    }
                    else 
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter image size your desired size ")

                }
    }
}
```

Comment: this sure is one method to get the desired result

Comment: @AmberYaseen if it resolved your problem , kindly click on the "accept answer' otherwise feel free to comment . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OpenFileDialog is likely concerned with simply selected a file on the file system.  Once you've selected, it is up to you to validate that selection meets the criteria, whatever that criteria may be.  So once selection is made, and you now know path to the file, use image library to load the file, validate that file loads without issues (remember, may not be a valid file to begin with), and then validate its dimensions.  If something doesn't pass, act accordingly, e.g. letting the user know why file is being rejected and suggesting picking a new one.